# Can I force `const` to pass by reference (aka the missing `in` parameter)

Tags: delphi, pass-by-reference

Delphi has:

`var` : pass by reference; parameter is both input and output.
`out` : pass by reference; parameter is output only.
`const`: pass by ..... well it depends; parameter is input only.
`in`  : <del>pass by reference; parameter is input only and will not be changed</del> there is no "in".

I don't mind that *[there is no spoon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzm8kTIj_0M)*, but I miss `in`; considering the following code, is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
type TFastDiv = record 
strict private
  FBuffer: Int64;
  other fields
....

//Must be `var` because `const` would pass a Int64 by value
//                      |||
//                      VVV
function DivideFixedI32(var Buffer: Int64; x: integer): integer;
asm  
  mov  r9,rcx                   
  imul dword ptr[rcx]    // do stuff with the buffer
  ..
  mov     ecx, [r9+4]    // do other stuff with the rest of the buffer
```

<sub>*{Changing the code to `imul ecx;...;shr r9,32;mov ecx,r9d` would allow pass by value, but let's assume the code must not be changed.}*</sub>

```
class operator TFastDiv.IntDivide(x:integer; const buffer:TFastDiv):integer;
begin
  Result:= DivideFixedI32(Int64((@buffer.FBuffer)^), abs(x)); <<-- Ugly
  if (x < 0) then Result:= - Result;
end;
```

`DivideFixed` will never change the buffer. The whole point of the routine is that `buffer` is a precalculated value that does not change.

In the class operator I declare buffer as const, because the record must not change.

**The question is:**
If I insist on declaring the `buffer` parameter in `IntDivide` as `const` is there a cleaner way of coding or am I stuck in the pointer_to/points_to hack?

Comment: What is `in`? What you are really missing is C++ `const MyType& value`

Comment: `in` would be the opposite of `out`, pass by reference but parameter is guaranteed to not change; and yes, a pointer (aka pass_by_reference) that will not be changed inside the routine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Newer compiler versions (from XE3 onwards) support the `[Ref]` decorator:

```
procedure Foo(const [Ref] Arg1: Integer; [Ref] const Arg2: Byte);
```

Example adapted from [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Constant_Parameters), which emphasises the `[Ref]` can go either before or after the `const` keyword.

Comment: +1 very nice. Do you know which compilers support this? Do the desktop compilers do so?

Comment: OK, I've been able to check this myself on XE5 desktop compiler, and [ref] is implemented there. So, I expect it is implemented everywhere.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan XE3 seems to be the first (just tried it), and yes, the desktop compilers too.

Answer (score 6):

The only option (pre Delphi XE3) if you want to ensure pass-by-reference, is to pass something big.
i.e. bigger than sizeof(pointer)

```
type TFastDiv = record 
strict private
  FBuffer: Int64;   <<-- make sure this is the first member
  other fields
....

function DivideFixedI32(const Buffer: TFastDiv; x: integer): integer;
...
class operator TFastDiv.IntDivide(x:integer; const buffer:TFastDiv):integer;
begin
  Result:= DivideFixedI32(buffer, abs(x));
```

This line in the [Delphi help file](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control#By_Value_vs._By_Reference):

> Sets, records, and static arrays of 1, 2, or 4 bytes are passed as 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32bit values. Larger sets, records, and static arrays are passed as 32-bit pointers to the value. An exception to this rule is that records are always passed directly on the stack under the cdecl, stdcall, and safecall conventions; the size of a record passed this way is rounded upward to the nearest double-word boundary.

is misleading and should be changed to/read as:

> > Sets, records, and static arrays up to SizeOf(pointer) are passed as 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32bit values (64 bit values on x64). Sets, records, and static arrays larger than SizeOf(Pointer) are passed as pointers to the value. An exception to this rule is that records are always passed directly on the stack under the cdecl, stdcall, and safecall conventions; the size of a record passed this way is rounded upward to the nearest SizeOf(pointer) boundary.